Probability distribution map for a diffraction experiment
Assume a single-photon propagates along $z$ in a glass fiber that terminates, creating an interface glass-vacuum. I'm interested in the diffraction pattern created after the fiber at a distance $z_s$.
Can you suggest an article or book that calculates exactly or numerically the diffraction pattern formed after many many photons have been passing $z_s$, starting from quantum physics laws/equations directly (not using at all classical optics/EM)?

I think the Airy disk formula.  I.e. no difference between a light exiting a fiber or light going thru a round aperture.

I think so as well. Would like to find the calculation that does not use classical approaches.

Use the Feynman path integral.  Model many paths from across the aperture to a single point on the screen, use trig to get each path length, from lambda get the phase for each and sum them all .... then repeat for another point on the screen ... plot net phase squared at each point on the screen.  Light prefers paths that are full wavelengths ... resonance... no light in the dark bands .... all photons in the bright bands.  Feynman agrees with Huygens ....Huygens is essentially based on a wavelength model as well.

Use the Feynman path integral. Model many paths from across the aperture to a single point on the screen, use trig to get each path length, from lambda get the phase for each and sum them all .... then repeat for another point on the screen ... plot net phase squared at each point on the screen. Light prefers paths that are full wavelengths ... resonance... no light in the dark bands .... all photons in the bright bands. Feynman agrees with Huygens ....Huygens is essentially based on a wavelength model as well.
